# SQLALchemy: joinedload function does not working after object expire

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
class Model:
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    rel = relationship(Submodel)
```

Two cases:

1)

```
model = self.session.get(Model, 1)
model.field = 'any'
self.session.flush()
return self.session.get(Model, 1, options=[joinedload("*")])
```

This is launched select query for each relationship of model.

2)

```
model = self.session.get(Model, 1)
model.field = 'any'
self.session.flush()
return self.session.scalars(
    select(Model)
    .options(joinedload("*"))
    .where(Model.id == 1)
).one()
```

This is OK, one lazy join query

Why I can't complete joinedload for session.get function after expire object?